# Obtener ubicación como una variable global

Tags: java, android, android-studio

tengo un problema tengo esta clase

```
public class Class_Session {
    private String idAgente = "";
    private double Lat = 0;
    private double Lon = 0;

    public String getIdAgente() {
        return idAgente;
    }

    public void setIdAgente(String idAgente) {
        this.idAgente = idAgente;
    }

    public Double getLat() {
        return Lat;
    }

    public void setLat(Double lat) {
        Lat = lat;
    }

    public Double getLon() {
        return Lon;
    }

    public void setLon(Double lon) {
        Lon = lon;
    }
}
```

La utilizo para crear un objeto que guarde la latitud y longitud mediante esta otra clase

```
Class_Session session = new Class_Session();
double lg, lt;
LocationManager locationManager;

public class LoginActivity {
    public void LocationStart() {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        final boolean GPSEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if(!GPSEnabled) {
            Intent configGPS = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(configGPS);
        }

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 00, locationListenerGPS);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 2 * 20 * 1000, 10, locationListenerGPS);
    }

    private final LocationListener locationListenerGPS = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            lg = location.getLongitude();
            lt = location.getLatitude();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "GPS Provider update", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    session.setLat(lt);
                    session.setLon(lg);
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
        }
    };
}
```

Una vez me cambio de actividad no puedo llevarme la inflacionario del objeto porque esta instanciado en la otra activity y si instancio uno nuevo perderé la ubicación. Que solución es factible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, aclare mi mente un poco, coloque la ubicacion en las sharedpreference en un metodo runOnUiThread() para que lo haga en segundo plano.

```
  Sharedpreference ubi = getSharedPreferences("Ubicacion", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  SharedPreferences.Editor editor = ubi.edit();
  editor.putString("lg" ,""+lg);
  editor.putString("lt" ,""+lt);
  editor.commit();
```

Ahora solo llamamos las preferencias donde las necesiten

```
  double uno,dos;
  ubi = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences("Ubicacion", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
  uno=Double.parseDouble(ubi.getString("lg",""));
  dos=Double.parseDouble(ubi.getString("lt",""));
```

En mi caso fue asi, gracias espero que a alguien le sirva de algo esta idea.